# I get the package name already used error when uploading android app

Tags: android, google-play, apk, package-name

When uploading the android app in Google Play, I got the error saying that the package name is already used. Instead of changing the package name everytime I upload the updated app, what are the other ways?

Comment: If it's an updated version of the same application, you only need to change the version number and update the apk.

Answer (score 0):

That tells you that another app with the same package name already exists. You have to change the package name in your java files, the Manifest / the Gradle file depending on the build type you use.

You cannot have another application with the same package name on the PlayStore, so there is no other way than changing the package name permanently.